# Counter in bash script

Tags: bash, counter

I have a script that extracts filenames from an input file and is supposed to read each line (filename) and unzip the specified file, saving the unzipped content as individual files. However, I can't get my counter to work and just get all the unzipped files in one large file.

```
Input file contains a list: 
ens/484/59/traj.pdb 0.001353
ens/263/39/traj.pdb 0.004178
ens/400/35/traj.pdb 0.004191
```

I'm using the `regex /.*?/.*?/` to extract the file that I'd like to unzip and name each `output{1..40}.pdb` -- instead I get one output file: `output1.pdb` which contains all the contents of the 40 unzipped files.

My question is: how do I correct my counter in order to achieve the desired naming scheme?

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/home/input.txt"
grep -Po '/.*?/.*?/' $file > filenames.txt
i=$((i+1))
structures='filenames.txt'

while IFS= read line
 do
   gunzip -c 'ens'$line'traj.pdb.gz' >> 'output'$i'.pdb'
 done <"$structures"

rm "$structures"
```

Comment: May be you meant to put `i=$((i+1))` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @EA00 Remember to double quote `$line` or else if it contains spaces your code will break: `gunzip -c 'ens'"$line"'traj.pdb.gz' >> ...` or: `gunzip -c "ens${line}traj.pdb.gz" >> ...`

Comment: @andlrc Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file="/home/input.txt"
grep -Po '/.*?/.*?/' $file > filenames.txt

structures='filenames.txt'
i=1
while IFS= read "line"
 do
   gunzip -c 'ens'$line'traj.pdb.gz' >> 'output'$i'.pdb'
   i=$(expr $i + 1)
 done <$structures

rm $structures
```

couple of logical mistakes, the counter has to be fined as `one` out of the while loop and the counter `+1` should be inside the loop, also for the  counter to work you have to use `expr,` in this case i made the counter start from `1`, so the first entry will get this value. Also on the parameter for the `while loop` i dont really understand what you are doing, if it works as you have it then cool or else use a `test statement` after while and before the parameters.

Comment: The temporary file and the spurious variables should be fixed as well.  Simply `grep -Po regex /home/input.txt | while IFS= read ...`

Comment: You cannot have a space before the equals sign in `IFS=`

Comment: Also as already pointed out in comments, the silly quoting doesn't do anything useful, and the quotes are missing where they would be required (or at the very least useful).

Comment: @tripleee does the while loop actually works with the parameters defined like this? cause depending on what he i checking there i think he needs the `test` thought

Comment: anyways, he said his problem was with the counter, so i just meant to clear how he can do that, for the rest, he should update the post...

Comment: @hedgehog - In the original code when I moved the counter inside the while loop and fixed the quotes, it seemed to work fine. But nonetheless I really appreciate all the input and as a beginner I can see how your code is more logically sound. Thanks!

Comment: @EA00 You are welcome, if you think the topic is closed and you dont have more questions about this, select one of the answers as the correct one so this topic closes.